# Why isn't my regular expression working in my php code

Tags: php

I am coding a login system, which based on the username, will then use a regular expression to decide which table to check, However, for some reason the regular expression doesn't seem to be working, and I am not sure why? The first part seems to be working howver the second part (the else statement does not, and I am not sure how come?

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is already logged in, if yes then redirect him to welcome page
if (isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) && $_SESSION["loggedin"] === true) {
    header("location: studenthomepage.php");
    exit;
}

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

function console_log($output, $with_script_tags = true) {

    $js_code = 'console.log(' . json_encode($output, JSON_HEX_TAG) .
');';
    if ($with_script_tags) {
        $js_code = '<script>' . $js_code . '</script>';
    }
    echo $js_code;
}

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

$mysqli = $db->get_con();
$pattern = "/[0-9]/";
if (preg_match($pattern, $_POST["username"]) == 1) {
// Processing form data when form is submitted
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Check if username is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)) {
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT studentUsername, studentPassword FROM students WHERE studentUsername = ?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()) {
                // Store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                    // Bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($username, $hashed_password);
                    if($stmt->fetch()) {
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                            
                            header("location: studenthomepage.php");

                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
} else {
    // Processing form data when form is submitted
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    // Check if username is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["username"]))) {
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if (empty(trim($_POST["password"]))) {
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if (empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)) {
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT teacherUsername, teacherPassword FROM teacher WHERE teacherUsername = ?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            
            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()) {
                // Store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                    // Bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($username, $hashed_password);
                    if($stmt->fetch()) {
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)) {
                            // Password is correct, so start a new session
                            session_start();

                            // Store data in session variables
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                            
                            header("location: teacherhomepage.php");

                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }

            // Close statement
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mentoring System</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
     body {
        text-align: center;
        }

        form {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ 
            width: 360px; 
            padding: 20px;
            border-style:solid;
            background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 39%, 0.3);
            backdrop-filter: blur(8px);
            /* position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            align: center; */
            margin: 5% auto;

        }
        body {
            background-image: url("background.jpeg");
        
            background-color: #cccccc;
            }
        .edit{
            width: 320px;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .ref{
            color: rgb(81, 88, 95);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2><img src="logo.png" class="edit" alt="logo"></h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <!-- <label>Username</label> -->
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder = "Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <!-- <label>Password</label> -->
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder = "Password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Login">
                <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="showpage.html" role="button">Home Page</a>
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a class = "ref" href="register.php">Sign up now</a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are a lot of conditions in your code. Best is to check all of them isolated. Also check the return value of `preg_match` - use strict comparison `=== 1` instead of `== 1`.

Comment: How is the regex not working, ie what are you expecting to happen? Also there is no `else` on your `preg_match` if statement.

Comment: What's your goal here? Currently the preg_match() checks if there's a digit in the username, if not the none of the PHP code runs(as that if clause wraps all of it)

Comment: the goal is, if there is a digit, the if statement clause runs, and if not, then the else statement should run, however it is not. The else statement is further down, just after the first mysqli close (line 103)

Comment: You have posted 245 lines of code using 6 different languages. Please focus this down to a very small amount of code. There should be no HTML, CSS, JavaScript or SQL, just RegEx, and if needed, PHP. When testing RegEx, don't use variables such as `$_POST`, always use literals such as `'my-test-string'`. Once a literal works, then you can introduce a variable. Here's a [sample](https://3v4l.org/NSFjO) of a very minimal RegEx/PHP that people can analyze and talk about. Also, for RegEx debugging in general, see https://regex101.com/

Comment: @DawudLatif Ok, like I said, then: Your current code looks like this: `if (preg_match(...)) { if (...) { } else { } }`. That is, the preg_match() check is _outside_ of your if statement. You need to rewrite (merge) them.